Macbook Air 2013 - 256GB SSD shows as 1.2GB in disk utility
I have "inherited" a 2013 MacBook Air with a 256GB SSD. The machine was formerly used with Windows 10 but I threw that out, along with the MacOS, and tried to install various versions of Linux (from flash drives). This was some time ago so I have to rely on a fuzzy memory here but I think at one point I had Ubuntu on it working. Then I tried to replace that with some other version of Linux. That somehow didn't go well and I ended up with the current situation. I have no functioning OS on the machine at all. Or at least, it appears that way. The disk utility in Internet Recovery shows a "Disk0", with a "MacOS Base" partition. "Disk0" appears to have a mere 1.2GB - when it should be 256GB. It can’t be erased/formatted or partitioned.
Diskutil in Terminal shows the same drive, "Disk0", and 11 more drives (Disk1, Disk2 etc.), see picture below.
I've tried reinstalling MacOS using the Internet Recovery but that doesn't work since the installer can't find a drive to install on.
I've also run the Apple Diagnostics tool and the only information I get from it is: "There may be an issue with a storage device. Reference Code: VDH002."
Is there something I can do to bring this drive back to a usable state?


Can we see some output from diskutil ?

If you tell me exactly what you want, I'll snap a picture and post it here. Just diskutil list? BTW, I'm in Japan where it's night now so I'll probably only respond in a half day or so.

I have added a picture of diskutil list results to the OP.

As also added to the post, I've run the Apple Diagnostics tool and the only information I get from it is: "There may be an issue with a storage device. Reference Code: VDH002."

FYI that 1.2GB partition is likely the EFI partition (to boot the system) and (in my experience) disk utility won't touch it. You can just ignore it.

Your disk seems faulty: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251290690?sortBy=best

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102334

@SteveChambers Yes but it's still a part of the SSD, no? So that would imply that the SSD is not necessarily physically defective.

@IconDaemon and lhf- thanks. The code legend doesn't shed any new light on this. It just restates what the message in Diagnostics said. Besides, I have contacted Apple support before and they said they can't help with an SSD that old.

Anyway, considering how much more time I may need to invest in this - if it can be fixed at all - I guess my best option is to find an original, still functioning SSD from a compatible MBA, install that, update to High Sierra and then swap out the old SSD for a new, NVMe one.

I would recommend reading this guide to Apple's proprietary SSDs, and which ones will be compatible. You should find loads on ebay - just make sure it's the right one. https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

@benwiggy: Thank you!

Just because one part of a 'disk' is working fine doesn't mean all parts are working fine. What I was trying to say was that deleting that partition is unnecessary and does not (in and of itself) prevent you from creating more partitions to install whatever OS you like.

@SteveChambers OK, got it. Thanks!
